# Obter dados de um relacionamento ManyToMany com Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine, framework, modelo-relacional, doctrine-2

Tenho o seguinte relacionamento N:N entre as tabelas professores e turmas, onde existe uma terceira tabela professores_turma.

Quero que ao listar os professores me traga todas as turmas que este professor leciona (**que está relacionado**), porém quando retorno a consulta dos professores, `$professor->getTurma()` vem vazio.

Segue meu código:

**Controller Professor:**

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class ProfessorController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->professores = $this->model->getRepository()->findAll();
        // Traz todos os professores, porém não traz suas turmas
        // com $professor->getTurmas()
        foreach ($this->professores as $professor) {
            var_dump($professor->getTurmas()); die();
        }
    }
}
```

**Entidade Professor:**

```
namespace App\Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="professores")
 */
class Professor
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     **/
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Turma", mappedBy="professores")
     **/
    private $turmas;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->turmas = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setTurmas($turmas)
    {
        $this->turmas = $turmas;
    }

    public function getTurmas()
    {
        return $this->turmas;
    }
}
```

**Entidade Turma:**

```
namespace App\Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection as ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="turmas")
 */
class Turma
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     **/
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Professor")
     * @JoinTable(name="professores_turma",
     * joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_turma",referencedColumnName="id")},
     * inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="id_professor", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     **/
    private $professores;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->professores = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function setProfessores($professores)
    {
        $this->professores = $professores;
    }

    public function getProfessores()
    {
        return $this->professores;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu havia respondido que o problema era a falta do parâmetro `inversedBy` no atributo `$professores` da classe `Turma`, mas testei aqui e não é isso. Inseri algumas linhas no banco de dados, tanto na tabela `professores` quanto na tabela `turmas` e na tabela relacional,  e consegui retornar as linhas normalmente. Você tentou fazer isso?

Comment: Opa +Rodrigo Rigotti, desculpa a demora de responder... Como você conseguiu? Voçê pegou por getRepository->findAll() todos professores com as turmas relacionadas para o atributo $this->turmas da Entidade Professor e tendo acesso a essas turmas a partir do método getTurmas() da Entidade Professor??? Como voçê fez? Tem como passar o código?

Comment: isso! reproduzi dentro de um projeto Symfony2, mas o processo é basicamente o mesmo. Vou colocar no Github pra vc.

Comment: Segue: https://github.com/rodrigorigotti/lala.git

Comment: O problema não era nem minhas entidades, mas sim a forma que estava tentando imprimir, assim: **`$professor->getTurmas()->getNome()`**. Ao invés de fazer um `foreach` em **`$professor->getTurmas()`**. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Como aprovar sua ajuda?

Comment: Não precisa. Se você achar necessário, adicione uma resposta explicando o que você fez de errado e valide sua resposta depois de alguns dias. :)

Comment: Blz. Obrigado Mais uma vez!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema não era nem minhas Entidades, nem nas Annotations e nem no relacionamento. Mas sim a forma que estava tentando imprimir, assim:

```
$professor->getTurmas()->getNome()
```

Tava errado, ao invés disso, tive de fazer um **`foreach`** em **`$professor->getTurmas()`**, ficou da seguinte forma no Controller de Professor:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class ProfessorController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->professores = $this->model->getRepository()->findAll();

        foreach ($this->professores as $professor)
            if ($professor->getTurmas()->count() > 0)
                foreach ($professor->getTurmas() as $turma)
                     echo 'TurmaId: ' . $turma->getId() . ' -> TurmaNome: ' . $turma->getNome() . '<br>';
    }

    /* ... */

}
```